How can I refactor the functions in my Flutter StatefulWidget?
The code below is a simple example of a Flutter widget I want to refactor, to improve both organization and readability.
I want to refactor _incrementCounter and _decrementCounter so that the _MySimpleWidgetState class isn't so cluttered. I've tried extending _MySimpleWidgetState class by moving the _incrementCounter and _decrementCounter functions there, but that made the code less readable.
What am I missing here? I vaguely recall knowing how to do this, but the technique isn't coming to mind right now. Please forgive me if this is something really basic.

class MySimpleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySimpleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySimpleWidget> createState() => _MySimpleWidgetState();
}

class _MySimpleWidgetState extends State<MySimpleWidget> {

  int _counter = 0;

  _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter--;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),

          child: Text('Counter Value: $_counter'),
        ),

        TextButton(onPressed: () => _incrementCounter(), 
        child: const Text('Increment Counter')),

        TextButton(onPressed: () => _decrementCounter(), 
        child: const Text('Decrement Counter'))
      ],
    );
  }
}


You can separate the logic code from UI, e.g creating a repo class for logic, use abstraction level, maybe just a facad. From your current snippet, I will remove the anonymous function onPressed: _incrementCounter,. You can find very good book e.g Clean Code, Refactoring, Design pattern... Few years back I wanted to write too clean code and spend quite a good time(year+) on refactoring. Now I just want to keep thing simple and refactor along side

I agree with @Md.YeasinSheikh, especially when you have a ton of function, you'll need to separate the logic and UI. It's really good to research clean code from the basic. At first i suggest you to learn implementing Effective Dart Style. This one helped me to coding in dart. Such as more readable function/variable, shortener code, good and bad approach code. Very recommended guide!

The key idea is to move the logic that doesn't directly involve UI concerns (in this case, the counter manipulation logic) out of the widget's state class. We can achieve this by introducing a separate class that handles the counter logic. This approach follows the Single Responsibility Principle, where the _MySimpleWidgetState will focus solely on the UI, and the counter logic will reside in a dedicated class.
Create a Separate Counter Logic Class: This class will handle the incrementing and decrementing logic. It keeps the state and logic related to the counter separate from the UI, making it easier to maintain.
Use the Counter Class in the State: The state class will delegate counter manipulation to the newly created counter logic class. The state class will still call setState() to notify Flutter of any changes, but it no longer needs to directly manage the logic itself.
class Counter {
  int value = 0;

  void increment() {
    value++;
  }

  void decrement() {
    value--;
  }
}

class MySimpleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySimpleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MySimpleWidget> createState() => _MySimpleWidgetState();
}

class _MySimpleWidgetState extends State<MySimpleWidget> {
  final Counter _counter = Counter(); // Instance of Counter class

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
          child: Text('Counter Value: ${_counter.value}'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _counter.increment();
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _counter.decrement();
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Decrement Counter'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Counter Class: This is a simple class that holds the counter's value and the logic for incrementing and decrementing the counter.
Separation of Concerns: The _MySimpleWidgetState no longer manages the logic for changing the counter value. Instead, it simply tells the Counter class to perform those operations and calls setState() to rebuild the UI.
Improved Readability: The _MySimpleWidgetState is now cleaner and only focuses on rendering the UI, making the code more readable and maintainable.
Hope this helps!
